# change h2 in title woocommerce products shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use the product shortcode [products ...]
it returns products grid with H2 title like the product grid in the category page.
how do I change the title from H2 to H4 only in products shortcode and not in the category page?

Comment: You can add class in the shortcode and write CSS for that class. `[products class="custom_class" ]` and `.custom_class{font-size:16px;}`

Answer (score 1):

The shortcode uses `content-product.php` template so to modify it you need to unhook `woocommerce_template_loop_product_title()` and hook your new title function. Add the following code in your active theme functions.php

```
remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_product_title',10);
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title','theme_template_loop_product_title',10);
function theme_template_loop_product_title() {
    //if is woocommerce page like shop, product category etc
    if(is_woocommerce()):
        echo '<h2 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
    else:
        echo '<h4 class="' . esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_loop_title_classes', 'woocommerce-loop-product__title' ) ) . '">' . get_the_title() . '</h4>';
    endif;
}
```